# Lua getting XOR key and decoding

Tags: file, lua, key, xor, decoding

I'm trying to get the key of a xor file and decode it using said key.

```
function GetKey(data)
    local base = {'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x',
    'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x',
    'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 
    'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x',
    'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x',
    'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x',
    'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'}
    local key = ""
    for i=0, 100 do
        key = key .. string.char(bit32.bxor(data:sub(i+1,i+1):byte(), base[(i%(#base))+1]:byte()))
    end
    return key:sub(65,65) .. key:sub(34,64)
end

function Decode(s, key)
    local i = 1
    s = s:gsub("(.)", function(t)
        if (i > key:len()) then
            i = 1
        end
        k = bit32.bxor(t:byte(), key:sub(i,i):byte())
        i = i + 1
        return string.char(k)
    end)
    return s
end

local s = io.open(select(1,...), "rb"):read("*a")

local key = GetKey(s)
print("Key found: " .. key)
print("Decoding...")
s = Decode(s, key)
local outfile = io.open(select(1,...) .. ".xor", "wb")
print("Finished!")
```

This is the code I have for getting the key and decoding.  At the moment it gets the wrong key and therefore decodes files incorrectly.

Anyone have any help or can give some pointers?

Thanks

Comment: and how about providing the correct key and what you get instead?